# The path of a disk/cylinder with translation and rotation

Tags: kinematics, friction, rotational-kinematics

**The conditions:**

> We have a regular disc of mass $\mathrm{M}$ and radius $\mathrm{R}$. It is placed on a horizontal plane **with friction** (which is constant throughout). It is then given an initial angular velocity $w_{0}$, and a horizontal initial velocity $v_{0}$.

**The question:**

> Determine the path of the disc over time.

I am having trouble analysing the situation. I am not sure if it would go straight or curve. I have tried taking a differential element of the disc, but then I do not know how I would go about quantifying the friction.

I need help in understanding how to analyse the situation at hand.

**A variation:** (which I think is harder because now we have to quantify the effects of toppling and asymmetry in friction)

> The conditions above are the same, but now we have a cylinder of height $\mathrm{H}$ placed on its circular base.

[image]

Comment: Some diagrams would really help visualize what's going on;  as it is, it's really unclear (especially the "variation".)  Can you edit your question to include them?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Apologies, I cannot do better than a hand drawn image. I hope that makes the situation clearer. As for the cylinder situation, we just give the disc a height $\mathrm{H}$ making it a cylinder.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this is as follows:

For a non-rotating disk, you would model the magnitude of friction as $|\mathbf{F}| = \mu M g$, with a direction directly opposite to that of the velocity. If you assume friction scales in proportion to area, then you can write the magnitude of friction on an area element as
$$ |\mathbf{dF}| = \mu M g \times\frac{dA}{\pi R^2}\;.$$

All I'm doing here is scaling the force down by fractional area.

To get the direction of the frictional force, all you need is to consider the direction of the velocity of that area element (remembering to normalise the magnitude to 1):
$$\mathbf{dF} = \mu M g \times -\frac{\mathbf{u}}{|\mathbf{u}|} \times\frac{dA}{\pi R^2}\; .$$

$\mathbf{u}(x,y)$ is just the velocity of the disk at a given point, which you should be able to work out from your knowledge of the motion of the disk. Once you know $\mathbf{u}$ you can integrate the frictional force over the whole disk to get the net force.

Comment: Note also that there may be a net torque on the object — or at least it's not obvious to me that there isn't.  This would be obtained by writing $\mathbf{d\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{dF}$ and integrating that quantity.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Indeed, although I'm starting to doubt the usefulness of this method for either integral. It seems pretty nasty to solve without assuming $\omega_0 >> v_0$ or something similar.

Comment: Oh, I highly doubt that the result will be "nice".  I'm pretty sure that the angular integral will spit out some kind of complete elliptic function, which you'd then have to integrate over the radial coordinate.